# How do I populate properties in an EF entity just before saving?

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an entity like this.  Let's say that name is the only :

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // immutable
    public string Name { get; set; } // can be changed

    // These are not exposed on the domain layer.  They're just bookkeeping fields.
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

If I populate the 2 "updated" fields before calling SaveChanges(), my entity will be erroneously marked changed if Name hasn't changed.  Therefore, I need an event on the DbContext to hook into in order to populate those 2 fields just before committing the unit of work, but only on entities that have actually changed.

Does such an event exist?  Can nHibernate do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add default values to a property when saving using Code First EF4.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500464/how-can-i-add-default-values-to-a-property-when-saving-using-code-first-ef4-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ObjectContext API you have event `SavingChanges` directly on `ObjectContext`. You can handle this event and use ObjectStateManager to find all modified / added entities and deal with them as you need.

In both [ObjectContext API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991383/update-object-on-saving/5991453#5991453) and [DbContext API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500464/how-can-i-add-default-values-to-a-property-when-saving-using-code-first-ef4-1/5503294#5503294) you can override `SaveChanges` method directly and do the same.

Fluent NHibernate is just NHibernate's extension for fluent mapping in code. NHibernate has much better support for such scenarios - it offers [custom listeners](http://www.codinginstinct.com/2008/04/nhibernate-20-events-and-listeners.html) to deal with this.